# differences with Euler transformation for series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have a question about the Euler Transformation in Konrad Knopp text.  The notation is as follows,

[image]

Now I want to prove this statement,

If $x_k$ is a null sequence and $ \triangleleft^n x_k > 0 $ for $  n,k = 0,1,2,...$, then $ \triangleleft^n x_o $ is a null sequence.

I don't know how to prove this but from the hypothesis I can prove these claims below:

1. Since $x_k$ is a null sequence, each row of the "triangle" ($\triangleleft$) is a decreasing null sequence.
2. Also, $ \triangleleft^{n+1} x_k < \triangleleft^{n} x_k , (n,k = 0,1,2...)$ i.e each diagonal of the "triangle" form a decreasing sequence as well.

But from all the properties I have above, I still can't show $ \triangleleft^n x_o $ is a null sequence. Can someone give me some tips? thank you very much.

Comment: the notation is $\Delta^n x_k$ \Delta, and null sequence means converging to $0$

Comment: Can you write in a clearer way? I don't get what you are trying to say,  thank you

Comment: Actually $ \Delta^n x_1 < 0 $ is wrong since by the hypothesis, $ \Delta^n x_k > 0 $ for all $ n,k = 0,1,2,... $

Comment: as I said I can show $\Delta^n x_1 \to 0$ : $\Delta^n x_0-\Delta^{n+1} x_0 = \Delta^n x_0-(\Delta^n x_0-\Delta^n x_1) = \Delta^n x_1 > 0$ so $\Delta^n x_0 > \Delta^{n+1} x_0$, hence $\Delta^n x_0$ is a decreasing positive sequence, and it converges to $c \ge 0$. So that $\Delta^n x_0-\Delta^{n+1} x_0 \to 0$ i.e. $\Delta^n x_1 \to 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement $\boxed{\lim_{k \to \infty} x_k = 0 \ \ \land \ \ \forall n,k, \ \Delta^n x_k > 0  \quad \implies\quad \lim_{n \to \infty}\Delta^n x_0 = 0}$ doesn't seem true.

- Take $y_0 = 1, \forall k \ge 1$, $y_k = 0$. You get $\Delta^n y_k = y_k$. Hence $\Delta^n y_k \ge 0$ but $\lim_{n \to \infty}\Delta^n y_0  = 1$.
  (note I could stop there, this is a proof)
- Take $z_k = e^{-k}$. It is clear that $\Delta^n z_k > 0$. Assume your statement is true, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}\Delta^n z_0 = 0$

  (it is since $\Delta^n z_k= \sum_{m=0}^n {n \choose m} (-1)^m z_{k+m} = \sum_{m=0}^n {n \choose m} (-1)^m e^{-k-m} = e^{-k} (1-e^{-1})^n$)
- Finally take $x_k = y_k +  z_k$. You have $\Delta^n x_k = \Delta^n y_k+\Delta^n z_k > 0$, but $\lim_{n \to \infty}\Delta^n x_0 = \lim_{n \to \infty}\Delta^n y_0+\Delta^n z_0 = 1$.

Comment: I forgot to add that $x_k$ is a decreasing null sequence, but either way, your counterexample works.  I kinda suspect it but couldn't come up with an example.  I guess Konrad Knopp made a typo in the text then.  thank you very much